# Find the area of the surface generated by revolving the curve

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the surface generated by revolving the curve $ \ x(t)=t^2+\frac{1}{2t} , \ y(t)=4 \sqrt t \ $ , $ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \leq t \leq 1 \ $ about the **y-axis.**

**Answer:**

The formula is

$ 2 \pi \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}^{1} x(t)  \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac{dy}{dt})^2} dt \\ \\ =  
 2 \pi \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}^{1} (t^2+\frac{1}{2t} ) \sqrt{4t^2-\frac{7}{4t}+\frac{1}{4t^4}} \ dt$

But this becomes complicated to evaluate the integral and even I can not evaluate it using computer also..

Can someone evaluate the integral even using computer ?

Is there shortest  way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint...the expression inside the square root should be $$(2t+\frac 12t^{-2})^2$$

Comment: Can you evaluate the integral what I have done  using any tools?

Comment: That wouldn't be an answer to your original question. Are you asking a different question?

Comment: Why not ? The integral which I wrote is the formula for parametric representation .  But the problem is I can not evaluate it. Do you help me ?

Comment: As I have said in my answer, the expression inside the square root should be something different to what you have written. Your integral is not correct.